How to get the comma seperated value of a column to display as next values in oracle apex grid
I have a query which results as below for the query
select store_id,error_message from SVC_UPLD where store_id = 19258;
STOREID  ERROR_MESSAGE
19258    Box Number is mandatory.,Quantity cannot have any special 
         characters.,BRAND is not a valid Brand in             
         MFCS.,RRP_CURRENCY is not a valid currency code in MFCS.,HSCODE 
         will be with Minimum as 8 
         chars,SEASON not a valid season.,Selling_Retail_curr is not a 
         valid currency code in MFCS.,GENDER             
         is not a valid Gender in MFCS.,COLOR is invalid.

I have tried using the below query
select regexp_substr (
           error_message,
           '[^,]+',
           1,
           level
         ) value
  from   SVC_UPLD 
  connect by level <= 
    length ( error_message ) - length ( replace ( error_message, ',' ) ) + 1;

**
Getting output as below
**
STOREID    ERROR_MESSAGE

19258      Quantity cannot have any special characters.
19258      BRAND is not a valid Brand in MFCS.
19258      RRP_CURRENCY is not a valid currency code in MFCS.
19258      HSCODE will be with Minimum as 8 chars
19258      SEASON not a valid season.
19258      Selling_Retail_curr is not a valid currency code in MFCS.
19258      GENDER is not a valid Gender in MFCS.
19258      COLOR is invalid.
19258      ALLOCATION SIZE is mandatory.

**
I need output as to show the error message in same grid cell as next next line
**
STOREID    ERROR_MESSAGE
19258      Box Number is mandatory.,
           Quantity cannot have any special characters.,
           BRAND is not a valid Brand in MFCS.,
           RRP_CURRENCY is not a valid currency code in MFCS.,
           HSCODE will be with Minimum as 8 chars,
           SEASON not a valid season.,
           Selling_Retail_curr is not a valid currency code in MFCS.,
           GENDER is not a valid Gender in MFCS.,
           COLOR is invalid.
``


I think you mean to break on the character ".," but keep all data in the same row. Here is one option for Interactive Report and Interactive Grid
Interactive Report
Use html break tag in the query:

SELECT storeid, REPLACE(error_message,'.,','<br>') as error_message FROM SVC_UPLD;

Then for the column "error_message" set attribute "Escape special characters" to "No"
Interactive Grid
Use a line feed and format using pre tag.
SELECT storeid, REPLACE(error_message,'.,',CHR(13)||CHR(10)) as error_message FROM SVC_UPLD;

Then in column error_message > Column Initialization JavaScript Function set
function(config) {     
    config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {         
        cellTemplate: '<pre>&ERROR_MESSAGE.</pre>'     
    };     
    return config; 
} 


Aren't you over-complicating things? From my point of view, replacing commas with <br> tags does the job.
Classic report whose source is
select STORE_ID,
       REPLACE(ERROR_MESSAGE, '.,', '.<br>') error_message
  from SVC_UPLD

Turn error_message column's "Escape special characters" property OFF.
Run the page; result is

